# Build automatically is not working in myecllipse

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

When I make changes to .java files those are not recompile automatically.i have set build automatically also.every time i made changes to the .java files and restarting my server.it is taking long time.

Is there anything in particular I need to do to get the java classes to recompile on change?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your changes does not reflect when accessing you app in the server. It is most probably compiling but not getting published to the server.

There is a setting in your server config, open it up and in Overview tab > Publishing section, make sure the chosen setting is "Automatically publish when resource change". Every save then not only compiles your code but also deploys the class file to your server.

Here is some typical way to config "auto publish" for servers in eclipse-based IDEs. (Note: sorry can only do links to screenshots!)

[Tomcat 7 server config screenshot](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-W58aAztHZXs/U7VgDf0LybI/AAAAAAAAAK4/nrSq6GefBzQ/w800-h351-no/tomcat+7.PNG)

[Jboss EAP 6.1 server config screenshot](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-_szs6sxGb30/U7Vf846S7wI/AAAAAAAAAKw/y2zXehXs9jA/w801-h357-no/jboss+eap+6.1.PNG)

Comment: opened server configuration selected my server(jboss 6.x) i didn't find publishing section can you help me how can i find it?..@jake.online

Comment: Added links to screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to Java files are only hot-synched with the server if the server is started in debug mode. Note, though, that not all changes can be hot-synched (for example, if you change a method signature).

I think the answer by Jake refers to the WTP server configuration that is in the eclipse Java EE distribution. The MyEclipse server configuration (up to release 2014) looks different, and  it doesn't include that setting (which is done automatically in debug mode). The latest release (a kind of beta release) of "2015 CI 1" does have a closer similarity to WTP server configuration (which is used under the covers), so the publish automatically setting should appear.

So, start your server in debug mode to get Java changes to automatically be published.